# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "${now}";

Tags: timestamp, h2, liquibase

I'm struggling with this problem from a few days without really understanding the reason behind it.
Working with Liquibase, PostgreSQL and H2DB (for testing).
Liquibase is working fine when working with PostgreSQL but as soon as I need to run the tests, which are executed on H2DB, they fail because of parse exception with the ${now} property, just if it was not replaced by the effective value (at least I think so).
This is my changeset for creating the table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="h2"/>

    <property name="now" value="current_timestamp" dbms="postgresql"/>

    <property name="floatType" value="float4" dbms="postgresql, h2"/>
    <property name="floatType" value="float" dbms="mysql, oracle, mssql"/>

    <!--
        Added the entity Container.
    -->
    <changeSet id="20180424154826-1" author="developer">
        <createTable tableName="container">
            <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>

            <column name="description" type="varchar(2000)">
                <constraints nullable="true" />
            </column>

            <column name="container_type" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="true" />
            </column>

            <column name="created" type="timestamp">
                <constraints nullable="true" />
            </column>
        </createTable>
        <dropDefaultValue tableName="container" columnName="created" columnDataType="datetime"/>

    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

and this the changeset for populating it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="h2"/>

    <property name="now" value="current_timestamp" dbms="postgresql"/>

    <property name="floatType" value="float4" dbms="postgresql, h2"/>
    <property name="floatType" value="float" dbms="mysql, oracle, mssql"/>

    <changeSet id="20180425154950-1" author="developer">
        <loadData catalogName="container"
                  encoding="UTF-8"
                  file="config/liquibase/containers.csv"
                  schemaName="public"
                  separator=";"
                  quotchar="'"
                  tableName="container">
        </loadData>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Here the CSV file used (working fine with PostgreSQL):

```
id;name;description;container_type;created
1;'Human';'Human container';HUMAN;${now}
2;'IT';'IT container';IT;${now}
3;'Physical';'Physical container';PHYSICAL;${now}
4;'Intangible';'Intangible container';INTANGIBLE;${now}
```

This is the full log of the exception:

```
2018-04-26 11:30:20.350 ERROR 17993 --- [           main] liquibase                                : classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20180425154950_added_Containers_data.xml::20180425154950-1::developer: Change Set config/liquibase/changelog/20180425154950_added_Containers_data.xml::20180425154950-1::developer failed.  Error: Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "${now}"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO public.container (id, name, description, container_type, created) VALUES ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}') -- ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}') [22007-197] [Failed SQL: INSERT INTO public.container (id, name, description, container_type, created) VALUES ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}')]
2018-04-26 11:30:20.352  WARN 17993 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [eu/hermeneut/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20180425154950_added_Containers_data.xml::20180425154950-1::developer:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "${now}"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO public.container (id, name, description, container_type, created) VALUES ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}') -- ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}') [22007-197] [Failed SQL: INSERT INTO public.container (id, name, description, container_type, created) VALUES ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}')]
2018-04-26 11:30:20.400 ERROR 17993 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [eu/hermeneut/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20180425154950_added_Containers_data.xml::20180425154950-1::developer:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "${now}"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO public.container (id, name, description, container_type, created) VALUES ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}') -- ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}') [22007-197] [Failed SQL: INSERT INTO public.container (id, name, description, container_type, created) VALUES ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}')]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20180425154950_added_Containers_data.xml::20180425154950-1::developer:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "${now}"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO public.container (id, name, description, container_type, created) VALUES ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}') -- ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}') [22007-197] [Failed SQL: INSERT INTO public.container (id, name, description, container_type, created) VALUES ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}')]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:619)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:214)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:431)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:94)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1688)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1626)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "${now}"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO public.container (id, name, description, container_type, created) VALUES ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}') -- ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}') [22007-197] [Failed SQL: INSERT INTO public.container (id, name, description, container_type, created) VALUES ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}')]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:309)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:113)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1277)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1259)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:582)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "${now}"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO public.container (id, name, description, container_type, created) VALUES ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}') -- ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}') [22007-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.value.ValueTimestamp.parse(ValueTimestamp.java:147)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:1071)
    at org.h2.table.Column.convert(Column.java:177)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:166)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:134)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:102)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:261)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:233)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:205)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:307)
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ${now}
    at org.h2.util.DateTimeUtils.parseDateValue(DateTimeUtils.java:345)
    at org.h2.util.DateTimeUtils.parseTimestamp(DateTimeUtils.java:460)
    at org.h2.value.ValueTimestamp.parse(ValueTimestamp.java:145)
    ... 69 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

Even for h2 database, the in built function to get current timestamp is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Reference here -> http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#current_timestamp

So change this

```
<property name="now" value="now()" dbms="h2"/>
```

to this

```
<property name="now" value="current_timestamp()" dbms="h2"/>
```